# Get column names for SVD in R

Tags: r, plot, svd

I am doing SVD in R on a data frame called data

```
svd1 <- svd(scale(data))
```

I plot the result using

```
plot(svd1$d^2/sum(svd1$d^2),xlab="Column",ylab="Percent of variance explained",pch=19)
```

I found out that in the plot, column number do not corespond to the column numbers in the data frame (no matter what subset of columns I use with SVD, the first column always shows the highes variance).

My question is, how do I get the column names (or "real" indices) in the plot?

Comment: Without a reproducible example or at least an exhausting summary, this will likely be doomed as too localized.

Comment: you can use any data frame you like to reporduce it. The question is how to "map" the columns of the data frame used to the output column numbers

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want. The singular values (from Lapack dgesvd at least) are sorted so that S(i) >= S(i+1). Lapack gives no correspondence between output and input columns. I don't think it's even possible.

Comment: Actually, SVD explicitly gives the mappings between the original matrix and the diagonal matrix D.  These mappings are linear transformations, and are typically called U and V*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the R documentation (.../library/base/html/svd.html):

```
d is a vector containing the singular values of x, of length min(n, p).
```

These singular values are computed by the SVD algorithm from the whole input matrix, so there is no way to label the singular values based on the column names.

Comment: so there is no way to know which of the variables is the most significat one and you only know how significat it is?

Comment: @IgorKulman: There is a way to determine which of the variables has most influence on each of the values of `d`. Given that X = U D V*, where D is a matrix containing only the singular values `d` along its diagonal and V* is the transpose of V, one can examine the linear transformation to determine this -- as advised by @Matthew Lundberg in his comment on the question. In some cases it may be that a given singular value has only a few important contributors from among the variables, which might enable some useful labelling for those cases, but that wouldn't be true in the general case.